# Is there any way to have a solution for this SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IImMO.png)

Query I used here is to get claimstatus by using case statement. But I am not getting the expected output.

For Num : 040523000374 (1st and 2nd row), where EventName does not have 'ClaimReassigned', then claimStatus is 'Not ClaimReassigned', it's working fine

But for Num : 047523000125 (3rd to 6th row) where EventName is `ClaimReassigned` for one of the Num, then `ClaimStatus` should be 'ClaimReassigned' for that number (047523000125) from 3rd to 6th row.

I used `CASE` statement as shown here:

```
CASE EventName
    WHEN 'ClaimReassigned' THEN 'ClaimReassigned'
    ELSE 'Not ClaimReassigned'
END
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- Add some data, show results, and then show what the expected results are.

Comment: Mysql and sql server are two very different database products with different implementations of sql. The screenshot was made in ms sql server management studio, so I assume you use sql server and I removed the mysql tag.

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text for data and (your attempt at) your query

Comment: In addition to posting your data as text (not an image), I think you need to more precisely describe what you are trying to accomplish here. As currently written, your `CASE` **expression** (it is not a statement) *is* performing as expected, because it only considers the `EventName` value on the current row.  Since row 4 is the only one with `EventName = 'ClaimReassigned'`, that is the only row where the `CASE` expression produces `'ClaimReassigned'` in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the window function with `Partition by Num` and `count()` any rows with `EventName` equal to `ClaimReassigned`

```
claimStatus = case when count(case when EventName = 'ClaimReassigned' 
                                   then 1 end) over (partition by Num) >= 1
                   then 'ClaimReassigned'
                   else 'Not ClaimReassigned'
                   end
```